# Is it possible to verify already existing solution by OptaPlanner to check how may rules get broken?

Tags: java, optaplanner

Here the already existing solution is generated by any other codebase/tool but we can adjust the attribute as per requirement for OptaPlanner.
Main aim is to verify that existing solution is breaking how many rules then the mature result from optaPlanner.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any specific error you are getting? Please read about ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's possible.

See docs section "explaining the score". Basically you use `SolverFactory.getScoreDirectorFactory()` to build a `ScoreDirector` and then use `setWorkingSolution()`, `calculateScore()` and then `explainScore()` (in that order).

Comment: These days, use `ScoreManager.explainScore()` instead.